# Apache Rewrite to Nginx+phpfpm with frontend\backend separating

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting, php

My project structure is

```
/
/...
/backend/www/...
/backend/www/index.php
/frontend/www/...
/frontend/www/index.php
```

/ - document root

rules is:

- when acessing site.com/css/style.css  it uses  /frontend/www/css/style.css
- when acessing site.com/unknown/url/without/extension it uses /frontend/www/index.php
- but when it prefix with /admin/*, for ex. site.com/admin/css/main.css it uses /backend/www/css/main.css, the same way with index.php - on any route prefix with /admin/* it will user /backend/www/index.php

I have Apache Rewrite rules in 3 files:

**/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?admin(.*)$ /backend/www/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) frontend/www/$1 [last]
```

and 2 other files:

**/frontend/www/.htaccess**, **/backend/www/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|css|js).* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

**How to create the same config for Nginx+phpfpm?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for someone to write some code for you, not an actual technical question.

Comment: I hope someone has similar configuration, this structure is popular when using frameworks.